# Django ifequal problem comparing 2 datatypes

Tags: django

`post.dys` is a String variable and `day.day` is an integer.

Both have the same value, but there is no output as expected.

I think it's a variable-type problem, but I'm not sure.

How can this be solved?

```
{% ifequal post.days|slugify day.day|slugify %}
   test
{% endifequal %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, two variables should the same type to work properly. See manual page for [python](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) and [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal). You may cast variable to same type using `str()` function in your view, for example.